# Version Control Hacking for a Kind of Forward Compatibility

Tags: git, forward-compatibility

(First paragraph is just context that may or may not be useful for the actual question(s).) I'm working on an application with a complex document format and a lot of weird legacy issues. We're interested in transitioning to a new format that's designed to play nicely with Git (and potentially other VCSs). We are developing custom diff and merge drivers for our format.

I think I've stumbled on a neat way to support a kind of forward compatibility, and I'm curious if anyone knows about this existing in the world already.

Let's say Alice is working on a project in version 73, and she wants to hire Bob, a contractor, to help with the project, but he only has version 67 of the software. I think a VCS workflow like the following sketch could make it reasonably convenient for them to collaborate.

```
        E---F---G---K        "downgraded" branch
       /             \
      /---------------L      "re-upgrade" commit
     /                 \
A---B----C----D----H----J-   trunk
```

Alice explicitly makes commit `E` to downgrade from 73 to 67; this probably involves removing some data and other format changes. Bob and Alice work concurrently for a while. Bob finishes with commit `K` and then Alice re-upgrades the downgraded branch by running a weird merge with the following inputs:

- Ours - `B`
- Theirs - `K`
- Base - `E`

This produces commit `L` in the diagram, which can then be merged back in using a vanilla merge or rebase or whatever.

Does this make any sense to anyone else? What would be the cleanest way to implement it in Git? I'm imagining some kind of `cherry-pick`, but if Bob's branch has some complicated internal branching/history hacking, I'm not sure if that's right. What I think I'm trying to get out of Git is just a delta between Bob's last commit (`K`) and the original downgraded commit (`E`), then applying this delta to the pre-downgrade commit (`B`)

Comment: There are workflows that deal with managing legacy versions of an application (like git flow). But no one, as far as I know, has envisioned anyone taking a working copy and making a new commit to revert it to an older version like this. Just branch out from the older commit instead!

Comment: @fredrik Thanks for the comment. If I understand you correctly, there is no "older commit" to branch from. Alice has been working on this project in version 73 from the beginning. She wants some way to incorporate new work from someone who can't or won't upgrade their application version.

Comment: Just make a branch from the latest and diff the changes. Apply what needs to be applied and commit that.

Comment: Re: The closure of this question. It seems strange to say that it "can[not] be answered with facts" when it got a nice fact-based answer in less than an hour. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest to what you're looking for here is a "rebase": take somebody's changes, and *re-apply them* in a new context.

If we take as our starting point the branch with the "downgrade commit" E at the start of it, plus another branch which doesn't have that:

```
        E---F---G---K  <--  "downgraded" branch
       /                
A----B----C----D----H   <--  trunk
```

In git, a "rebase" allows us to create a new branch with *just the changes from F, G, and K* on top of the new base H:

```
        E---F---G---K  <--  "downgraded" branch
       /                
A----B----C----D----H   <--  trunk
                     \
                      F2---G2---K2   <-- rebased changes
```

In git, this would be something like `git rebase F K --onto H`, or could be achieved with an interactive rebase by deleting the todo line for commit E.

Alternatively, you can rebase onto the base B, and then perform a normal merge:

```
        E---F---G---K  <--  "downgraded" branch
       /                
A----B----C----D----H---M   <--  trunk
      \                /
       F2---G2---K2---+  <-- rebased changes
```

The key either way is that you want commit E *not to be in the final history*. This is somewhat cleaner than the even simpler solution, which is simply to *revert* commit E (reverse the changes it made, creating a new commit "ER") at the end of the process, and then merge from there:

```
        E---F---G---K---ER---+
       /                      \
A----B----C----D----H----------M   <--  trunk
```

Comment: Thanks. Conceptually this makes sense to me. My advanced Git hacking skills are modest. As I understand rebase, it would include "E" by default. How do you tell Git to start with "F"?

Comment: @BenYlvisaker There's a form of the `git rebase` command where you tell it the old base and the new base, rather than it finding the common ancestor; there's also an "interactive" form where you can edit the list of commits to rebase and (among other things) remove any you don't want.

Comment: Based on a tiny bit of experimentation it looks like `git revert` does something different from what I originally thought I wanted, but it might just do the trick. My custom merge driver is invoked with Ours = HEAD of the downgraded branch; Theirs = Pre-downgrade commit; Base = Post-downgrade commit. Thanks.

Comment: @BenYlvisaker "revert" in git is just "cherry-pick" in reverse; or if you're familiar with patch files, "apply the patch in reverse".

Comment: That makes sense. One thing I have been a little wary of is exactly what "apply the patch" means operationally in the context of custom data formats. I believe it means run the custom merge driver with Ours=Version to apply the patch to; Theirs=Minuend; Base=Subtrahend. But I haven't seen that spelled out in any documentation.